# Error con NEW y OLD en PL-SQL con disparadores (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql, trigger

!Buenas!

Estoy realizando este ejercicio:

> Al insertar o modificar un vendedor, hay que asegurarse de que el id
>   no coincide con ningún id de cliente. Si coincide se insertará, pero
>   se registrará en una tabla nueva a modo de log.

Donde el modelo relacional queda de esta forma:

```
Clientess (id, nombre)
Vendedores (id, nombre)
Ventas (id_clienteFK, id_vendedorFK, importe, fecha)
tabla_log(id,tipo,descripción)
```

E intentando realizar el ejercicio, estoy probando con esta solución:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insertar_vendedor BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON vendedores
DECLARE 
idCliente number;
BEGIN
select id into idCliente from clientess where clientess.id = :new.id;
if (idCliente%FOUND) then
INSERT INTO tabla_log values (1,'insertar','Se ha insertado un vendedor');
ELSIF (idCliente%NOTFOUND) THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No hay conincidencia');
END if;
END;
```

Pero me ha saltado este error, y la verdad que estoy empezando con los **Triggers** y estoy bastante perdido... A ver si alguien sabe como estructurar este ejercicio.

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que debes usar FOR EACH ROW en tu disparador para que se haga a nivel de fila, es decir, para que lo dispare cada vez que intentes insertar o actualizar.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insertar_vendedor BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON vendedores
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    idCliente number;
BEGIN
    select id into idCliente from clientess where clientess.id = :new.id;
    INSERT INTO tabla_log values (1,'insertar','Se ha insertado un vendedor');

    exception
      when no_data_found 
      then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No hay conincidencia para id: ' || :new.id);

END;
```

Edito porque preguntar por FOUND o NOTFOUND en un `SELECT INTO` simplemente no sirve para nada. Si no hay coincidencias, va a arrojar una excepción, que es la que se manejaría en el bloque exception. [[respuesta en SO en inglés]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13075674/236345)

Comment: Si lo intento de esta forma, no me aparece el error que he marcado. Pero me dice esto otro: **El atributo de cursor no puede aplicar a un no cursor IDCLIENTE5/5**

Comment: Edité la respuesta y creo que está mejor

Comment: Decirte que muchas gracias, me has solucionado un problema que ni mi profesor pudo decirme correctamente.

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudar :)